# serialize object as null based on one of its properties

Tags: .net, json, serialization, json.net

In a Newtonsoft Json.NET custom `JsonConverter`'s `WriteJson` method, can I appeal the the default object serialization behavior from within a `JsonConverter`?

That is, can I defer to the serialization that would have happened if the custom converter had not been registered?

### Details

Given a Price class

```
public class Price
{
    public string CurrencyCode;
    public decimal Amount;
}
```

the normal Newtonsoft Json.NET behavior is to serialize a `Price` instance as null only when the reference is null.  Additionally, I'd like to serialize `Price` instances as null any time `Price.Amount` is zero.  Here's what I have working so far ([complete source code](https://gist.github.com/EdVinyard/173ed1e6011f52f56aa2))

```
public class PriceConverter : JsonConverter 
{
    // ...

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, 
        object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer) 
    {
        var price = (Price)value;

        if (0 == price.Amount) {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        // I'd like to replace the rest of this method with an appeal to the 
        // default serialization behavior.
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("amount");
        writer.WriteValue(price.Amount);
        writer.WritePropertyName("currencyCode");
        writer.WriteValue(price.CurrencyCode);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    // ...
}
```

The last part of this implementation is brittle.  If I were to, for example, add fields to `Price`, my serialization would be broken (and I don't know a good way to write a test that'll detect the break).

My serializer has a number of behaviors, configured in a separate assembly via [JsonSerializerSettings](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm), that I need to preserve (e.g., camel-case property names).  It's not possible for me to add a direct dependency between these two.  In reality, I'm using the `[JsonConverter(typeof(PriceConverter))]` attribute to specify that my custom converter should be used for `Price`.

Comment: Currently converters don't have access to the settings, and the library's author seems to have no plans on implementing this. See this issue: http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/23794 You may try submitting a feature request on https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues I think converters which only slightly modify serialization are quite widespread, so it will indeed be a useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround to let converters receive settings -- you can use serialization context.

Set up:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { /*...*/ };
settings.Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All, settings);
```

In converter:

```
var settings = (JsonSerializerSettings)serializer.Context.Context;
```

I feel dirty when I do it though.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this approach?

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings MySettings()
{
    return new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind,
        };
}
```

In your `PriceConverter`:

```
if (0 == price.Amount)
{
    writer.WriteNull();
    return;
}
else
{
    writer.WriteRaw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Somewhere.MySettings()));
    return;
}
```

And in your program:

```
    public static void Custom(Price p)
    {
        var settings = Somewhere.MySettings();
        settings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new PriceConverter() };

        Console.WriteLine("custom: " +
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, settings));
    }
```

Comment: Good question.  My serializer has a number of behaviors, configured elsewhere via [JsonSerializerSettings](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) that I need to preserve (e.g., camel-case property names).  I'll update the question to include this information.

Comment: Can you add those `behaviors` to the gist?

Comment: I added an example of the settings I'm trying to preserve to the gist.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you're looking for (maybe i don't get the true nature of the problem), but i revised my answer...

Comment: Another good point.  The settings and the `Price` class are defined in separate assemblies, and dependency injection considerations prevent me from referring to a global settings builder as you suggest.